# ubuntu application to show calendar with week numbers

Tags: calendar

I would like to view a calendar for the current month, with each week having a week number against it. Is there an application to do this?

Comment: The properties under the clock / calendar can be adjusted to do that.

Comment: Please see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic

It works on my 12.04(Classic-gnome2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default time & calendar indicator applet has this built it - you just need to enable the option.

[image]

Comment: Has the settings menu been dumbed down? I could not see such an option in Ubuntu 11.10 running Gnome Shell and hence I had to do http://askubuntu.com/a/226443/32792

Comment: This menu for Time and date settings is disabled in my system. what do i do?

Comment: @vipin8169 - please create a new question with a link back to this one.  Give details of your system - show some screenshots of the issue

Comment: created, but i am not sure of how to link the two. http://askubuntu.com/questions/114032/ubuntu-application-to-show-calendar-with-week-numbers/114033?noredirect=1#comment800202_114033

Answer (score 8):

Running `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.calendar show-weekdate true` solved the problem for me.

---

On Ubunu 20.04, the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.calendar show-weekdate true
```

enables week numbers in the calendar widget.

Comment: There's something missing here.  Under both 12.04 and 12.10 this results in the error message: "No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.calendar'"

Comment: @fabricator4 I am running Gnome Shell instead of Unity.

Comment: Still works like a charm in Ubuntu 13.10 with GNOME (Shell) 3.10, with the exception of a slight misalignment of the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

On 12.04 after moving from unity to gnome-shell, I had to

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-week-numbers true
```

to have weeknumbers in the calendar notification applet.

Answer (score 2):

As [user1333445](https://askubuntu.com/users/149714/user1333445) advised to look at [answer 130006](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic#answer-130006) I installed [dconf-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dconf-tools) for my Ubuntu 18.10:

- `$ dconf-editor`
- navigate to: `/org/gnome/desktop/calendar/show-weekdate`
- turn `OFF` *Use default value*
- set to `True` *Custom value*
- click the *checkmark* at the bottom to apply

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way in Ubuntu 20.04:

- Install »GNOME Tweaks«

```bsh
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

- Menu »Top bar« > Section »Calendar« > Toogle »Show week numbers«

Answer (score 1):

This is not acutally a calendar application, but it displays the week numbers: The Gnome-Calendar applet. A screenshot from Gnome2:

[image]