# How do I enable week numbers in calendar applet when settings are missing?

Tags: indicator, calendar

I really want the time/date indicator applet to show me week numbers on the monthly view, and found this answer on how to enable: [ubuntu application to show calendar with week numbers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114032/ubuntu-application-to-show-calendar-with-week-numbers)

However, my settings does not look like this, just a stripped down version without tabs, why? Is there a config file somewhere I can set this?

Settings screenshot:

[image]

On Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Classic

Comment: +1 because I am trying to accomplish the exact opposite. I have week numbers showing, but I want to get rid of them. Hopefully, an answer will show how to toggler for either preference.

Comment: I added a bug report linking to this question: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1107662

Comment: Please see this link:http://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic

It works with classic-gnome on 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update the `gnome-control-center` to get the rest of the features working.

***Edit:***
 After googling, found that this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/961275). The fix says you need to update.

Comment: That bug was marked as closed in April, but the option as described in the question is still not available as of the latest version of gnome-control-center: `1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4`. At least, I can't see it, and I have all the latest packages as far as I know.

Comment: Same for me, at lastest version 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4, no update available..

Answer (score 0):

On 12.04 after moving from unity to gnome-shell (looks like your screenshot), I had to

```
   gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-week-numbers true
```

to have weeknumbers in the calendar notification applet.